# Understanding SBI and CBI in Arduino Inline Assembly

Tags: assembly, arduino, inline

I am attempting to write a small blink program in Arduino using inline assembly. The code under the first label (start:) works, and the LED turns on; however, the issue is with jumping to stop. In theory, this seems correct- I set the bit into register 5, bit 5 and then clear the bit, but this is not working.

```
void setup(){
    asm("sbi 0x05, 5");
}

void loop(){
    asm("start:");
    asm("sbi 0x05, 5");
    asm("jmp stop");

    asm("stop:");
    asm("cbi 0x05, 5");
    asm("jmp start");
}
```

I'm a newbie to inline assembly in Arduino, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the timing for the assembly instructions yet?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, no I haven't. Would that be a factor? The LED turns on, but not off, which leads me to think that at no point, is there any attempt to clear the bit

Comment: look here http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=4114.0

Comment: Erm, yes, it would be the primary factor on why your code fails (or rather, *doesn't* fail, but doesn't give the results you want).

Comment: Where's a delay after led on and after led off? If you don't insert such a delay the led blinks so fast that you cannot see it blinks!

Comment: I suggest you to read the manual of your micro and see how to use a timer or a counter. You may call a function that manages the timer after led-on and after led-off. The function should simply set values that sets a timer for a time that satisfies your requirements and waits for such a time elapses. The instruction `jmp stop` is not useful, you may substitute it with the first call to the function that sets the time. The second `call` should be inserted before the `jmp start` instruction.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: Makes sense, thank you. I'll work in a delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm):

"asm statements may not perform jumps into other asm statements. GCC does not know about these jumps, and therefore cannot take account of them when deciding how to optimize. Jumps from asm to C labels are only supported in extended asm."

Considering the documentation, I think you will have better luck if you include **all** of the assembly in one asm call. This allowed me to acquire the desired functionality you describe in your question.